# finding vector value belonging to each interval

Tags: r

I have two vectors with different length in R and I can combine these two vectors. I want to find vector values which belongs to each interval:

```
x = c(1, 2, 3.5, 4, 6, 7.5, 8, 9, 10, 11.5, 12) 
y = c(2.5, 6.5) 

w = sort(c(x, y))
```

I want to find the vector values x which less than 2.5 and the vector values x belong to interval (2.5, 6.5) and the vector value x bigger than 6.5?

Actually the value of vector y change in each iteration of my algorithm, for eaxample maybe I have vector y with length=4 so how can I find the vector value belongs to each interval in each iteration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
> split(x, findInterval(x, y))
$`0`
[1] 1 2

$`1`
[1] 3.5 4.0 6.0

$`2`
[1]  7.5  8.0  9.0 10.0 11.5 12.0
```

Here's what happens when we change `y`

```
> y = c(2.5, 6.5, 10.5)
> split(x, findInterval(x, y))
$`0`
[1] 1 2

$`1`
[1] 3.5 4.0 6.0

$`2`
[1]  7.5  8.0  9.0 10.0

$`3`
[1] 11.5 12.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the function `cut()` to divide a vector into intervals:

```
cut(x, breaks=c(-Inf, y, Inf))

 [1] (-Inf,2.5] (-Inf,2.5] (2.5,6.5]  (2.5,6.5]  (2.5,6.5]  (6.5, Inf] (6.5, Inf] (6.5, Inf] (6.5, Inf] (6.5, Inf] (6.5, Inf]
Levels: (-Inf,2.5] (2.5,6.5] (6.5, Inf]
```

Comment: +1, I would slightly modify cut(x,c(min(x),y,max(x)),include.lowest=TRUE) to get information about extremes.